How can I see the content of a cshtml file in browser developer tool?
Right now I am facing the problem that I have a error in my JS code. I am developing in .net core mvc web. The browser console is telling me this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (Create:172:70)

Which would mean there is an Error in line 172 of the file "Create". Somehow as you can see in the attached image, I can't see any content of this file in the developer tool.
Screenshot Edge browser:

Can someone help me out?
I couldn't find anything related to this issue.

Are you wanting to see a partial view source or your base .cshtml? In your screenshot, the Create.cshtml source code can be seen after you refresh the page when you developer tool is opened. You can directly click on the error which in your case is Create:172:70 and see the exact line where it is thrown.

To view the content of a CSHTML (Razor view) file in a browser's developer tools, follow these steps:
Open Developer Tools: In most browsers, press F12 or right-click on a webpage and select "Inspect" or "Inspect Element."
Find the Network Tab: Click on the "Network" tab to see all network requests made by the browser.
Reload the Page: Refresh the page to capture network traffic.
Filter by XHR/Fetch: To find server-side resources, filter by "XHR" or "Fetch."
Identify the CSHTML Request: If the CSHTML content is returned through an AJAX call or similar, look for relevant requests. Otherwise, focus on HTML content.
View Response: Click on the request to view details. Check the "Preview" or "Response" tab to see the server's response.
Note: CSHTML files themselves aren't sent to browsers; they're server-side templates used to generate HTML. In developer tools, you'll only see the final rendered HTML output.

Was this AI-generated?
